# How to auto run Firefox .xpi extension on webpage load

Tags: php, firefox-addon

Hi i have this firefox addon i would like it to automatically popup with download when a user loads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just redirect the user using javascript to the `.xpi` file?

At the end of your page, just before the `</body>` tag, put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = 'path/to/your.xpi';
</script>
```